# how compress file to zip with password use mozilla/zipwriter

Tags: mozilla

how add password when use mozilla/zipwriter compress file to zip?

I use below code, It work great！

```
let zipFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("AChrom",Components.interfaces.nsIFile); 
zipFile.initWithPath(zipFile.path+"\\smad.zip"); 

const PR_RDONLY  = 0x01; 
const PR_WRONLY  = 0x02; 
const PR_RDWR  = 0x04; 
const PR_CREATE_FILE = 0x08; 
const PR_APPEND  = 0x10; 
const PR_TRUNCATE = 0x20; 
const PR_SYNC  = 0x40; 
const PR_EXCL  = 0x80; 

let zipWriter = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/zipwriter;1","nsIZipWriter"); 
let zipW = new zipWriter();
zipW.open(zipFile, PR_RDWR | PR_CREATE_FILE | PR_TRUNCATE);
zipW.addEntryFile(pathComponent.pop(),Components.interfaces.nsIZipWriter.COMPRESSION_DEFAULT,fileItem,false);
zipW.close();
```

But How add password?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the [nsIZipWriter](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/b38e3beb658b80e1ed03e0fdf64d225bd4a40327/modules/libjar/zipwriter/nsIZipWriter.idl) does not seem to support passwords. Nothing is mentioned in the IDL definition or the [implementation](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/b38e3beb658b80e1ed03e0fdf64d225bd4a40327/modules/libjar/zipwriter/nsZipWriter.cpp).